# Math mode in knitr

Tags: math-mode, knitr

How do one use a math-mode in `knitr`? For example as a label for X-Y axis:

```
<<fe, echo=FALSE, sanitize=TRUE, dev="tikz">>=
    plot(1:10, main="${}^{57}Fe$", xlab="$\\\\lambda$", ylab="\\\\$I\\\\$", pch=20, family="CM Roman")
@
```

This produces the `$I$` and `$lambda$` as a labels.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use latex (such as math mode) directly in the images, you will need to install the R package `tikzDevice`, and also the Latex package `tikz` for Latex (and you will need to explicitly put `\usepackage{tikz}` in your document).

```
<<fe, dev="tikz", fig.cap = "${}^{57}Fe spectrum$", echo=FALSE>>=
    plot(1:10, xlab="$\\lambda$", ylab="$I$", pch=20, family="CM Roman")
@
```