# Special characters and math-mode in tikz graphics using knitr

Tags: tikz-pgf, r, knitr

This question closely relates to this one: [Using '$' in a tikz plot generated by knitr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209837/using-in-a-tikz-plot-generated-by-knitr)

I am able to get tikz graphics using knitr working with math mode as in this post:
[Math mode in knitr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109569/math-mode-in-knitr)

What I can't work out how to do is get both math mode working and special characters like '%' and '$' to show up as text.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: In TeX you need to escape those characters so `\%` and `\$` should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have worked it out. In the character objects in R, the escape character also needs to be escaped.

For example, using sanitize=FALSE (or omitted) in the knitr chunk, and using "\\$" works:

```
<<fe, dev="tikz", fig.cap = "${}^{57}Fe spectrum$", echo=FALSE>>=
    plot(1:10, xlab="$\\lambda$", ylab="\\$", pch=20)
@
```